# Teaching myself .net How would Garbage Collection handle this example

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, garbage

So I had a few questions about garbage collection.

```
void send_email()
{
    EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
    message.Subject = "AQState";
    message.Body = Environment.MachineName + " AQState = " + get_AQState();
    message.ToRecipients.Add("email@email.com");

    message.Send();
}
```

If I have a program that called send_email() once every hour how would GC handle the object created at hour 1 then hour 2 then hour 3. So every hour it would create a new message object would GC get rid of the old ones or what? Also what is considered better practice? what you see above or below

```
namespace AQState_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            send_email();
        }

    void send_email()
    {
        message.Subject = "AQState";
        message.Body = Environment.MachineName + " AQState = " + get_AQState();
        message.ToRecipients.Add("email@email.com");

        message.Send();
    }
```

I am self taught at programming and I greatly enjoy it but find myself missing some of the basics if someone could recommend a book to teach me the basics and give me a better foundation that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` keyword will always generated a new instance of the required class. As soon as the instance is unreachable, i.e. at the end of the `send_email()` method in your first example, the instance will be marked as eligible for garbage collection. Therefore, it cannot be re-used once there's no code that can affect it.

In the second example, as the `message` instance belongs effectively to the entire `Program` class, then it will not be marked as eligible for garbage collection until the `Program` class is out of scope, which, if the naming convention is as it appears, would mean that it would not be garbage collected at all, and the memory would only be reclaimed when the program exits.

Whichever is better depends on what other members of the `Program` class require access to the message. Ideally, you wouldn't want to expose the `message` instance to other parts of the `Program` class that don't need to know about it, so if nothing other than the `send_email()` method needs access to the `message` instance, then keep with the first version.